# Apache Spark - Reduce Step Output (K, (V1,V2, V3, ...)

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have a chronological sequence of events `(T1,K1,V1),(T2,K2,V3),(T3,K1,V2),(T4,K2,V4),(T5,K1,V5)`. 
Both keys and values are strings.

I am trying to achieve the following using Spark

```
K1,(V1,V2,V5)
K2,(V3,V4)
```

This is what I tried

```
val inputFile = args(0)
val outputFile = args(1)
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd1 = sc.textFile(inputFile, 2).cache()
val rdd2= rdd1.map {
    line =>
        val fields = line.split(" ")
        val key = fields(1)
        val v = fields(2)
        (key, v)
    }
// TODO : rdd2.reduce to get the output I want
rdd2.saveAsTextFile(outputFile)
```

Could someone please point me towards how to get the reducer to produce the output I want? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can refer to the docs, in the part of transformation(`groupByKey`, `aggregateByKey` ). http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to group your rdd by key to achieve the desired output: `rdd2.groupByKey`

This small spark-shell session illustrates the usage:

```
val events = List(("t1","k1","v1"), ("t2","k2","v3"), ("t3","k1","v2"), ("t4","k2","v4"), ("t5","k1","v5"))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(events)
val kv = rdd.map{case (t,k,v) => (k,v)}
val grouped = kv.groupByKey
// show the collection  ('collect' used here only to show the contents)
grouped.collect
res0: Array[(String, Iterable[String])] = Array((k1,ArrayBuffer(v1, v2, v5)), (k2,ArrayBuffer(v3, v4)))
```